# has / have been appropriated?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number

I was told that sums of money take a singular verb. What about the following sentence? Which auxiliary verb should be used?

> Eight million dollars **have/has** been appropriated for research into this strain of the virus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were told correctly. "Eighty million dollars" is not to be taken as eighty million separate amounts of one dollar, but as a single amount. "Has" is correct.

[Purdue.edu subject-verb agreement](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/subject_verb_agreement.html)

> 7. Nouns such as civics, mathematics, **dollars**, measles, and news require singular verbs.
>    The news is on at six.
>    Note: The word dollars is a special case. When talking about an **amount** of money, it requires a singular verb, but when referring to the dollars themselves, a plural verb is required.
>    *Five dollars **is** a lot of money.*
>    *Dollars **are** often used instead of rubles in Russia.*

[Emphasis added]

Comment: But I saw "Five million dollars **have** been appropriated for research into the disease" in Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary.

Comment: I consider that expression incorrect.

Comment: I'd consider this to be a case where both are possible, depending on, as Jack says, whether we are considering it as a singular amount of money, or a plural number of dollars.

Comment: Honestly, I think the quoted advice is just wrong.  _Civics_, _mathematics_, _measles_, and _news_ are not plurals; they are uncountable nouns that end with the letter _s_: if Sue has two mathematics and her mother gives her three more mathematics, how many mathematics does she have?  Any plural subject can take a singular verb when considered as a unity: four woman is too many to date at once; two meals a day is likely to leave you hungry; three examples is enough.

Comment: I don't think the reference said they were plural. "Four woman"?

Answer (score 1):

An American would certainly say “Eight million dollars *have* been appropriated for research...”  The British have a much more expansive sense of when a plural becomes a collective noun, so they might do it differently.